# How to create pojo with same xml tag in child and parent

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

I am having an xml which has xml tags **(states)** same as that of parent and child. So while creating the pojos using the jaxb xjc command, I am getting 2 static inner classes with same name. I tried using bindings.xml but my problem didnt resolve and instead I am not getting error. Please find all the details below

XML:

```
<universe>
<cotest>
<test>
<country>
<states>
<requirement type="op">
<states>
<cashitem>
<currency>usd</currency>
<val>o</val>
</cashitem>
</states>
</requirement>
</states>
</country>
</test>
</cotest>
</universe>
```

This is XSD thats I generated online

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Technologies Online Tools 1.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="universe">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="cotest">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="test">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="country">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="states">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="requirement">
                                  <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                      <xs:element name="states">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                          <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="cashitem">
                                              <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                  <xs:element name="currency" type="xs:string" />
                                                  <xs:element name="val" type="xs:string" />
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                              </xs:complexType>
                                            </xs:element>
                                          </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                      </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**bindings.xml**

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false" fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="true" choiceContentProperty="true" localScoping="toplevel"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings  schemaLocation="abc.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:schema//xs:element[@name='universe']//xs:sequence//xs:element[@name='states']//xs:complexType//xs:sequence//xs:element[@name='states']">
    <jaxb:class name="object2" />
</jaxb:bindings>

    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I am executing xjc using the command **xjc -b bindings.xml -d photos -p com.test1 abc.xsd**

error:

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "com.test1.States" is already in us
e. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 17 of file:/D:/user/abc.xsd

[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "States" is generated from here.
  line 23 of file:/D:/user/abc.xsd

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 17 of file:/D:/user/abc.xsd

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 23 of file:/D:/user/abc.xsd

Failed to produce code.
```

If I dont use bindings.xml then i can see classes are generated but have duplicate inner classes and hence my eclipse IDE shows compile time error
 command: **xjc -d photos -p com.test1 abc.xsd**

```
package com.test1;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "cotest"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "universe")
public class Universe {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Universe.Cotest cotest;

    public Universe.Cotest getCotest() {
        return cotest;
    }

    public void setCotest(Universe.Cotest value) {
        this.cotest = value;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "test"
    })
    public static class Cotest {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected Universe.Cotest.Test test;

        public Universe.Cotest.Test getTest() {
            return test;
        }

        public void setTest(Universe.Cotest.Test value) {
            this.test = value;
        }



        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "country"
        })
        public static class Test {

            @XmlElement(required = true)
            protected Universe.Cotest.Test.Country country;


            public Universe.Cotest.Test.Country getCountry() {
                return country;
            }


            public void setCountry(Universe.Cotest.Test.Country value) {
                this.country = value;
            }

            @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
            @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                "states"
            })
            public static class Country {

                @XmlElement(required = true)
                protected Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States states;


                public Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States getStates() {
                    return states;
                }


                public void setStates(Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States value) {
                    this.states = value;
                }



                @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
                @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                    "requirement"
                })
                public static class States {

                    @XmlElement(required = true)
                    protected Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement requirement;


                    public Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement getRequirement() {
                        return requirement;
                    }


                    public void setRequirement(Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement value) {
                        this.requirement = value;
                    }

                    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
                    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                        "states"
                    })
                    public static class Requirement {

                        @XmlElement(required = true)
                        protected Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement.States states;
                        @XmlAttribute(name = "type", required = true)
                        protected String type;


                        public Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement.States getStates() {
                            return states;
                        }


                        public void setStates(Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement.States value) {
                            this.states = value;
                        }


                        public String getType() {
                            return type;
                        }


                        public void setType(String value) {
                            this.type = value;
                        }



                        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
                        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                            "cashitem"
                        })
                        public static class States {

                            @XmlElement(required = true)
                            protected Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement.States.Cashitem cashitem;


                            public Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement.States.Cashitem getCashitem() {
                                return cashitem;
                            }


                            public void setCashitem(Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement.States.Cashitem value) {
                                this.cashitem = value;
                            }

                            @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
                            @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                                "currency",
                                "val"
                            })
                            public static class Cashitem {

                                @XmlElement(required = true)
                                protected String currency;
                                @XmlElement(required = true)
                                protected String val;


                                public String getCurrency() {
                                    return currency;
                                }


                                public void setCurrency(String value) {
                                    this.currency = value;
                                }


                                public String getVal() {
                                    return val;
                                }


                                public void setVal(String value) {
                                    this.val = value;
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

and this is objectfactory

```
package com.test1;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;



@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {


    public ObjectFactory() {
    }
    public Universe createUniverse() {
        return new Universe();
    }

    public Universe.Cotest createUniverseCotest() {
        return new Universe.Cotest();
    }
    public Universe.Cotest.Test createUniverseCotestTest() {
        return new Universe.Cotest.Test();
    }
    public Universe.Cotest.Test.Country createUniverseCotestTestCountry() {
        return new Universe.Cotest.Test.Country();
    }
    public Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States createUniverseCotestTestCountryStates() {
        return new Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States();
    }
    public Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement createUniverseCotestTestCountryStatesRequirement() {
        return new Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement();
    }

    public Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement.States createUniverseCotestTestCountryStatesRequirementStates() {
        return new Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement.States();
    }
    public Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement.States.Cashitem createUniverseCotestTestCountryStatesRequirementStatesCashitem() {
        return new Universe.Cotest.Test.Country.States.Requirement.States.Cashitem();
    }

}
```

As you can see from the universe classs, there are 2 static inner classes **public static class States** and this is the issue.
Can you any please provide a solution?
Let me know if any more information required.

Comment: Enhance the bindings file to give an explicit class name to one (or both) of the `<states>` elements. Do some research, and learn what you can do with the bindings file. It's fairly obvious, once you learn, which specification in the bindings file is used to name the class.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your guidance. I didnt know if the problem can be resolved by bindings.xml as I still learning. It would be great if you can post an answer so that I can accept

Comment: I posted links to 3 answers up top. Why would I create another answer saying what they already say?

Comment: @Andreas Thank you so much, I didnt notice that. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Andreas I have trying since whole day but could not solve. I have also tried to modify the binding xml , Can you please share your expert guidance in solving the issue?

Comment: You need to refer to the `<xs:complexType>` node, since it's the type you're naming. Shortest XPath for uniquely identifying the inner `states` type is with the following `node` value: `<jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='requirement']//xs:element[@name='states']/xs:complexType">`. I would recommend you give the class a better name, e.g. `<jaxb:class name="RequirementStates" />`

Comment: @Andreas You are genious. Its working. I have a doubt, since my other class name is RequirementStates so when I convert the java to XML again then my xml will have original states or it will come as RequirementStates?